# Ggplot round value in geom_text label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I calculate the value in the labels on-the-fly. It returns values with lozt's of decimals. How can I set it to one decimal?

```
plot.title = paste0('Subjectivity by sentence cluster')
cb2<-ggplot(sent_txt, aes(x=as.factor(best_cl), fill=as.factor(subjectivity_bin3_labs)))+
  geom_bar(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]), position="dodge" ) +
  geom_text(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..], label=scales::percent(..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]) ),
            stat="count", position=position_dodge(0.9), vjust=-0.5)+
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  labs(title=plot.title, subtitle = paste0('wordembedding: ', scope,', optimal method: ', best_method), fill="subjectivity class" ) +
  xlab("cluster") +
  ylab('subjectivity class, %') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) 
cb2
plot.nme = paste0(scope.prefix,'_',best_method_dr,'_',best_method_cl,'_sentence_subjectivity_distribution.png')
plot.store <-paste0(report.loc,plot.nme)
ggsave(plot.store, height = graph_height, width = graph_height * aspect_ratio, dpi=dpi)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example data and an image of the plot.

Comment: Simply use `round`?